# A school exam about other and the other

Tags: articles

Can you please explain how I can choose between these two options?

This peach is rotten, but _______ in the box are good.

1. other peaches
2. the other peaches

Answer (score 2):

The difference is whether you are speaking about all peaches left in the box or not.

> This peach is rotten, but the other peaches in the box are good.

This means that all of the other peaches, all the peaches left in the box are good.

> This peach is rotten, but other peaches in the box are good.

This on the other hand means that there are other peaches that are good, and those good peaches are in the box. But it doesn't necessarily mean that *all* the peaches in the box are good. Among the peaches left in the box may be some rotten ones.

So "other peaches" in this case is more general than "the other peaches".

Answer (score 1):

"*...**the** other peaches...*" means *all of* the other peaches.

"*...other peaches...*" means *some of* the other peaches.

Comment: That's weird!